# Cronoa Composer

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I just got introduced to Composer so I still don't understand how does it work exactly. I am trying to transfer an already working game into composer but I have been messing around with this code for a good 5 hours and still can't get it to work properly - the physics are not working properly, neither does the event listeners. If anyone is willing to lend me a hand I'll greatly appreciate it.
Here is the code https://github.com/DFrogBinder/Coursera-cource/blob/gh-pages/Game/Play.lua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few typos that may be causing some of the physics issues, but I am unsure exactly what issues you are having.

```
--> Walls and Ceiling
   local left_Wall = display.newRect(0, 500 , 1, display.contentHeight)
   local Right_Wall = display.newRect(display.contentWidth, 500, 1, display.contentHeight)
   local Celling = display.newRect(300, 0, display.contentWidth, 1)

   physics.addBody(left_Wall, "static", {bounce = 0.3})
   physics.addBody(Right_Wall, "static", {bounce = 0.3})
   -- Here, you have "Ceiling" rather than "Celling" that you defined above
   physics.addBody(Ceiling, "static", {bounce = 0.8})
   sceneGroup:insert(left_Wall)
   sceneGroup:insert(Right_Wall)
   sceneGroup:insert(Celling)
```

Here, you seem to have used event.x and event.y, which I am sure you are meaning to put event.target.x and event.target.y

```
local function moveCrate (event)
  local Crate = event.target
  Crate:applyLinearImpulse( 0, -20, event.x, event.y )
end
```

If you are having issues with composer when switching to the "Game Over" scene, it may be because you are not removing your display objects at the end of this scene.

Comment: I have corrected the typos as far as for the moveCrate function in the original (working) code it is event.y however I changed it to event.target.x and event.target.y, but to no result. I am still getting the error "attempt to call method 'applyLinearImpulse' (a nil value)", other that that the physics engine does not seem to work as the crates are just standing stationary at their spawn points in the air.

Comment: You are setting your gravity before the physics has started. Try calling your physics.start() before creation, or set gravity and such after your physics has started. In addition, I don't believe you can call composer.gotoScene() during a collision.

Comment: Yea, noticed it literally 2min ago, everything is ok now, thanks